# Can a Glamour Bard use the Enthralling Performance ability while casting Motivational Speech?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, bard

Can the following two mechanics work together or are they mutually exclusive or require something else? I am the DM. Both the player at my table and I don't agree or understand if it's possible to utilize **Enthralling Performance** in conjunction with the spell *motivational speech*.

**Enthralling Performance** (Glamour Bard ability)

> Starting at 3rd level, you can charge your performance with seductive, fey magic.
>
> If you perform for at least 1 minute, you can attempt to inspire wonder in your audience by singing, reciting a poem, or dancing. At the end of the performance, choose a number of humanoids within 60 feet of you who watched and listened to all of it, up to a number equal to your Charisma modifier (minimum of one). Each target must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw against your spell save DC or be charmed by you. While charmed in this way, the target idolizes you, it speaks glowingly of you to anyone who speaks to it, and it hinders anyone who opposes you, avoiding violence unless it was already inclined to fight on your behalf. This effect ends on a target after 1 hour, if it takes any damage, if you attack it, or if it witnesses you attacking or damaging any of its allies.
>
> If a target succeeds on its saving throw, the target has no hint that you tried to charm it.

**Motivational Speech** (Acquistions Incorporated, p.77)

> 3rd-level enchantment
> Casting Time: 1 minute
> Range: 60 feet
> Components: V
> Duration: 1 hour
>
> You address allies, staff, or innocent bystanders to exhort and inspire them to greatness, whether they have anything to get excited about or not. Choose up to five creatures within range that can hear you. For the duration, each affected creature gains 5 temporary hit points and has advantage on Wisdom saving throws. If an affected creature is hit by an attack, it has advantage on the next attack roll it makes. Once an affected creature loses the temporary hit points granted by this spell, the spell ends for that creature.

Does using one of these preclude using the other at the same time?

Comment: Welcome to our stack and thanks for putting up this question! Please take our [tour] to learn more about we operate and I hope we're able to help you and your table. If you could also clarify what you mean by RAI (please see [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7528/please-avoid-using-the-rai-acronym-or-use-it-carefully-be-clear-in-context?) about the confusion around that term.)

Comment: So to clarify, the question is basically "Does stacking these two effects take 2 minutes or 1 minute?" There doesn't appear to be any sort rules interactions between the effects besides the will save and advantage on will saves. Is it just being stingy about effect duration, or picky about time to prepare?

Comment: @NautArch Thank you for the welcome!  And thanks for the link about RAI, I had no idea.  I changed the title.
EDIT - Yeah that's actually a good idea.  Thank you for doing so!  Love going to this website all the time to clear questions up and after this experience I'll definitely do so more often.

Comment: @Kommissar Essentially yes.  I know it's being nitpicky but at this point I'm moreso arguing with my friend for the sake of delving into minutae, we're weird and think it's fun sometimes.  I don't really have a problem allowing it as I don't think it breaks anything, but I'm of the opinion that RAW and "the spirit of the game" it's not allowed.

Comment: You may want to add the specific things you're unsure about (if you know them.) It could be whether or not both mechanics can occur simultaneously, or whether or not the Spell counts as a performance, etc.

Comment: @ KRyan Good point, thanks.

@ KorvinStarmast We're wondering about either circumstance.

@ NautArch The post as it is now asks exactly what I want to ask now (thanks by the way!)

Comment: Out of curiosity - what was the bard hoping to achieve as an end-effect by combining these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It is up to the DM, though seems unlikely.

***Motivational Speech* does not say in its description that it is a performance**. This means it does not fulfill the requirements to perform for a minute in order to use *Enthralling Performance*. If the DM were to rule that it does count as a performance then the rules on casting come into play.

To cast *Motivational Speech* requires only a Verbal component, and 1 minutes of casting.

> **Longer Casting Times**
>
> Certain spells (including spells cast as rituals) require more time to cast: minutes or even hours. When you cast a spell with a casting time longer than a single action or reaction, **you must spend your action each turn casting the spell**, and **you must maintain your concentration while you do so**. If your concentration is broken, the spell fails, but you don't expend a spell slot. If you want to try casting the spell again, you must start over. *(Player's Handbook, Chapter 10, pg 202)*

I have emphasized the most important part of the description, that you must spend your action each turn casting the spell and you must maintain concentration. Now concentration isn't really an issue as *Enthralling Performance* does not require concentration.

However, the Components section on Spells states that for Verbal:

> Most spells require the **chanting of mystic words**. The words themselves aren't the source of the spell's power; rather, the particular combination of sounds, with specific pitch and resonance, sets the threads of magic in motion. *(Player's Handbook, Chapter 10, pg 203)*

Casting *Motivational Speech* is not just the Bard saying/doing something motivational, it also requires them to mix in mystic words which cause their words to have a motivational affect. What inspires the targets of *Motivational Speech* is not the words said, it is the magic behind them. One could rule that performing at the same time as casting the spell would cancel it as they are not spending their action chanting mystic words to cast the spell.

---

Another thing to mention is the Wisdom save for *Enthralling Performance*, and the Advantage on Wisdom saves provided by *Motivational Speech*. If you were to allow both of them to be cast in the same minute, you could rule that they have advantage on their Wisdom save for *Enthralling Performance*. As a result, you could suggest that they actually perform *Enthralling Performance* first, and then cast *Motivational Speech* if they don't want that affect to stack.